# Distance education programs in physics

Tags: soft-question, education, mathematics

I am a postgraduate in mathematics, shifting from mathematics to physics. I studied physics during my B.Sc.studies.I want to go for further studies in physics particularly in theoretical physics. I am in a job and cant afford regular classroom teaching. Could anyone tell me something about some distance education programs? or are there programs for mathematics graduates to work in theoretical physics areas like string theory?

Answer (score 2):

A respectable online resource for learning physics outside the traditional classroom setting is Gerard 't Hooft's website "Theoretical Physics as a Challenge" (type into the search command "Gerard 't Hooft, Theoretical Physics as a Challenge").

Answer (score 2):

There's a fantastic resource called by the National Programme on Technology Enhanced Learning. Check it out at http://nptel.iitm.ac.in/. They have a youtube channel as well http://www.youtube.com/nptelhrd where they post full courses online.

You will have to use these resources to study for the GATE and get into a good institute if you want to be paid for doing research. Considering you already have a BSc, I think you can do it if you devote your weekends to it. Leave a comment on this post if you need any more details.

Answer (score 1):

aren't there 'distance universtiy courses' in your country ??

since you are a mathematician you have the 'math stuff' perhaps you should begin with the list given by Gerard T'Hooft at http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~hooft101/theorist.html#bottom

there are good references of book and many of them can be 'downloaded' from the net :D